# When setting up a bridge for KVM, how can autoconnect for ethernet be disabled so the bridge still works after a reboot?

Tags: networking, network-manager, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, nmcli

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Baremetal server, ssh access only
Using nmcli to configure network

Guides followed:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-kvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-headless-server/
https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/creating-an-ubuntu-kvm-networked-bridge-interface/

I'm setting up a KVM and have created a bridge so the guests can network externally. All of the guides I've been following have led me to disable my ethernet connection and set up a bridge master and slave, which works. However on reboot, the ethernet connection returns and blocks the bridge.

Before reboot:

`root:/$ nmcli connection show`
`NAME        UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE`
`br0         8e347424-9ffc-4d5c-9fe6-715c23219786  bridge    br0`
`bridge-br0  3dd5d5a9-28d1-48d9-a537-1f6d14528428  ethernet  enp3s0`
`virbr0      348cc1a6-90eb-422e-b994-72daf4811615  bridge    virbr0`

`root:/$ nmcli device`
`DEVICE  TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION`
`br0     bridge    connected               br0`
`virbr0  bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0`
`enp3s0  ethernet  connected               bridge-br0`
`lo      loopback  unmanaged               --`

After reboot:

`root:/$ nmcli connection show`
`NAME        UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE`
`br0         8e347424-9ffc-4d5c-9fe6-715c23219786  bridge    br0`
`enp3s0      5111945c-55bb-4937-ac41-ac25da5140ef  ethernet  enp3s0`
`virbr0      3e8ca585-1e43-457d-affd-ccae25eb08f0  bridge    virbr0`
`bridge-br0  3dd5d5a9-28d1-48d9-a537-1f6d14528428  ethernet  --`

`root:/$ nmcli device`
`DEVICE  TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION`
`br0     bridge    connected               br0`
`virbr0  bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0`
`enp3s0  ethernet  connected (externally)  enp3s0`
`lo      loopback  unmanaged               --`

I can fix it manually by running this script:
`#!/bin/bash`
`nmcli con down enp3s0 && nmcli con up br0`

But not via (root) cron, the up part runs but the down part does nothing. Both work if I run the cron script manually.

I've tried checking autoconnect rules, this is how they are currently set. I've rebooted / reloaded since setting these values:

`root:/$ nmcli -f name,autoconnect con`
`NAME        AUTOCONNECT`
`br0         yes`
`enp3s0      no`
`virbr0      no`
`bridge-br0  yes`

Other things of note:

`root:/$ ip a`
`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000`
    `link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00`
    `inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
    `inet6 ::1/128 scope host`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
`2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000`
    `link/ether d4:5d:64:7c:ff:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
    `inet 89.xx.xx.29/25 brd 89.xx.xx.127 scope global enp3s0`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
`3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000`
    `link/ether 52:54:00:f7:54:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
    `inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
`4: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000`
    `link/ether 4a:42:6a:76:98:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
    `inet 192.168.2.25/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global noprefixroute br0`
       `valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Notably br0 is state DOWN, but ping 192.168.2.25 does respond.

Journal log: https://tempaste.com/Cow2Mvvhbcv

Tried: adding 'no-auto-default=enp3s0' to [main] in '/etc/NetworkManager', but this brought about no change.

My current thinking is that perhaps enp3s0 needs some sort of profile to not start automatically?
Perhaps cron isn't working because the network is not yet fully set up on reboot?

How can I get the bridge to continue working after a reboot?

Comment: Update: After reading Network Manager's documentation (https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html), my current thought is that adding 'no-auto-default=enp3s0' to [main] in '/etc/NetworkManager' might work. However I risk bricking the device if this is incorrect as I have no physical access and the host does not provide snapshots. If anyone is able to weigh in on this plan, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: I don't know about others, but the issue I have with trying to help with this one is that you are using network manager. On a server I only use systemd/networkd.